# Story that involved an army with eagles being defeated by cannon

Tags: story-identification

The plot points I remember are:

At the start, there are two armies about to fight, one has eagles(the good guys) and has never faced the cannon of the opposition. The battle goes badly for the good guys as their eagles are shot down by the cannon/some sort of ranged weapon.

Later in the book a character discovers prisoners from the battle being used as slaves.

I think is might be similar to the Redwall books, in that the characters are anthropomorphic animals. Much kudos to the person who can identify it from those vague details!

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: When did you read it? Young adult? Etc, any details you can remember. :)

Comment: Primary school in late 90s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like it could be [Eagle Warrior](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Eagle_Warrior.html?id=EQ0sAQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y), by Roger Mortimer.

It's set in the Mouse Kingdom of Carminel, and starts with the final battle of a civil war between the King's forces, supported by the Eagle Warriors and the Cardinal's forces who have cannons - which the King's forces did not expect. Most of the eagles are either killed or scared off by the cannons (not used to the noise).

The plot revolves around the characters finding Gideon (leader of the Eagle Warriors, went missing at the battle), the Prince of the Kingdom, and the crown in order to overthrow the Cardinal. Afraid I can only remember Gideon's name, and haven't been able to find a summary through Google.

About two-thirds of the way through two characters are captured by pirates, and taken to a secret gold mine where the captured Eagle Warriors and soldiers are being worked as slaves.

It was first published in 1998, so that fits the timing given in the OPs comment.

Also has two sequels: Eagle's Revenge (2000), and The Ruby of Carminel (2002)

Comment: Excellent find!